# Why does echoing $result->fetch_object()->id twice throw the error: "Trying to get property of non-object?"

Tags: php, mysqli

The second echo below throws the error "Trying to get property of non-object?"  The first echo prints fine.

```
$sql = "SELECT id
        FROM files
        WHERE url = '$url'";

$result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

echo "companyId: " . $result->fetch_object()->id;
echo "\ncompanyId: " . $result->fetch_object()->id;
```

I've doubled up the echo for simplicity of demonstrating this error.  I'm actually trying to check if $result->fetch_object()->id is set and then do something with the value if it is.  I can't get that to work correctly because the second time i use it, it throws the error "trying to get property of non-object."

```
if(isset($result->fetch_object()->id))
    echo $result->fetch_object()->id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysqli-resultsets works with cursors. This means, if you call `fetch_object()` the object is fetched (of course), the cursor moves on and now the previously retrieved object not present in the resultset anymore. Retrieve the object into a variable and interact with that, instead of calling `fetch_object()` multiple times.

```
$o = $result->fetch_object();
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `fetch_object()` the pointer moves to the next row, so the second time you call it you get the result of the next row or `NULL` if there are no more rows.

Take a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php); code like this would result in an endless loop if the pointer would not move to the next row:

```
/* fetch object array */
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj->Name, $obj->CountryCode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a reference to it:

```
$result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
$id = $result->fetch_object()->id;

echo "companyId: " . $id;
echo "\ncompanyId: " . $id;
```

Comment: what's actually happening that makes the original code not work?

Comment: KingCrunch explained it very well, actually.